# Is there a ring for which the reducibility of a polynomial is undecidable?

Tags: lo.logic, ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, decidability

Let $R$ be a ring such that all of its elements have a finite number of divisors, ie $\forall r\in R\, |\{x\in R: x|r\}|<\infty$.
Then we can decide whether a polynomial in $R[t]$ is reducible through [Kronecker's method](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Kronecker_method).

Even in the ring $\mathbb{Q}[x,\sqrt{x},\sqrt[4]{x},...]$, where $x$ has an infinite number of divisors, it is easy to list any polynomial's possible factors, and reducibility is decidable.

Is there a ring for which the reducibility of a polynomial is undecidable?

Is there a countable ring with computable ring operations and decidable equality for which the reducibility of a polynomial is undecidable?

Comment: I would ask for a countable ring with computable ring operations and decidable equality but undecidable reducibility.

Comment: Yes that is a good suggestion @Matt F.. Btw, where could I find an examplu of ring with uncomputable operations?

Comment: Consider $R=\mathbb{Z}[\{x_i\}]/\{x_i^2-f(i)\}$, where $f$ is a total function that grows uncomputably fast. In the presentation where the elements of $R$ are listed as elements of $\mathbb{Z}[\{x_i\}]$, the ring operations are computable but equality is not decidable. In the presentation where the elements of $R$ are listed as elements of $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}x_1+\mathbb{Z}x_2+\cdots$ (allowing only linear powers of the $x$'s), the equality is decidable but the ring operations (esp multiplication) are not computable. For a genuinely computable presentation of a ring you want both.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, but the answer is a bit unsatisfying. This answer is a summary of the very nice paper [Computable Fields and Galois Theory](https://qcpages.qc.cuny.edu/%7Ermiller/Notices.pdf), Russel Miller, *Notices of the AMS*, 2008.

First of all, if one could not even compute with the elements of the ring $R$ at all, it would be unclear what it would mean for factorization to be computable. The usual solution is to talk about "computable rings", meaning a countable (or finite) ring $R$ where the elements are indexed by integers and the operations of addition and multiplication are given by computable functions.

The following is an example of a computable field in which factorization is not decidable: Let $p_n$ be the $n$-th prime and let $T_n$ be the $n$-th Turing machine and let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_n} \ : \ T_n \ \mbox{halts})$. Given any element $\theta$ of $K$, there is a finite expression which witnesses that $\theta$ is in $K$: namely, the algebraic expression for $\theta$ in terms of finitely many $p_n$'s and a transcript of the ruunning of the corresponding Turing machines. This can be made into a proof that $K$ is computable, in particular (in response to Matt F.'s comment) there is no issue with testing equality. However, $x^2 - p_n$ is reducible iff $T_n$ halts, so we cannot test reducibility.

The fields one normally meets in life do not have this issue. Reducibility is computable over $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R} \cap \mathbb{Q}^{\mathrm{alg}}$ and over finite fields. If reducibility is computable over $k$, then it is computable over $k(t)$ and over $k[t]/f(t)$ for $f$ irreducible. That already covers the most obvious fields you know.

Searching for "computable fields" turns up a fair bit of recent research.

Comment: +1. Let me add to this that there's a surprising (to me at least) computable algebra fact here: while this undecidability result prevents the usual construction of the algebraic closure from being computable in the appropriate sense it is still the case that every computable field has a computable algebraic closure (Frolich-Shepherdson if I recall correctly). The subtlety here is around the phrase "algebraic closure:"  for every computable field $F$ there is a computable field $G$ such that $G$ is isomorphic to the algebraic closure of $F$, but no embedding $F\rightarrow G$ need be computable!

Comment: Your ring $K$ is not computable? Why?

Comment: @MarkSapir It is computable, but factorization is not decidable. I think that is what I wrote?

Comment: Yes you wrote it. You did not explain why is it computable.

Comment: This is going to be a mess to write out but: Each element of $K$ is writable as $\sum_{J \subseteq I} c(J) \prod_{i \in I} \sqrt{p_i}$ where $I$ is some finite index set and $c$ is a function from subsets of $I$ to $\mathbb{Q}$. It is easy to add, multiply and test equality of expressions in this form. (continued)

Comment: For each $N$, take the first $N$ Turing machines and find all those which halt in $\leq N$ steps; call this list $\mathcal{T}(N)$. Note that $\mathcal{T}(N)$ is finite. Consider all functions $c : 2^{\mathcal{T}(N)} \to \mathbb{Q}$ where the numerator and denominator of all numbers in the image is between $-N$ and $N$. This is still a finite list; call it $\mathcal{K}(N)$. (continued)

Comment: Every element of $K$ is described by an expression in some $\mathcal{K}(N)$. Breaking ties within $\mathcal{K}(N)$ in some manner, we indexed $\bigcup \mathcal{K}(N)$ by positive integers so that $+$, $\times$ and $=$ are computable (continued)

Comment: The definition of computable field in Miller's article requires that my elements elements be indexed by $\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, not by equivalence classes for a computable equality relation, but that is easy to deal with: Modify the definition of our set to only include those expressions in $\bigcup \mathcal{K}(N)$ which are not equal to an expression which we listed sooner.

Comment: Pinging @MarkSapir , since I forgot to do it when I started writing this.

Comment: I do not understand steps 2 and on. You said it is all written in some published paper?

Comment: Miller sketches this argument in slightly less detail than I do (page 8).

Comment: I see. The problem is that the definitions of "computable ring" used by Miller and you are  very weak. The ring $K$ is not recursive because there is no way to tell if $\sqrt{p}$ is in $K$. Of course if one uses recursively enumerable sets instead of recursive, it is easy to build all sorts of examples.

Comment: Are you sure you want to claim computability over $\mathbb{R}$? From what I understand, $\mathbb{R}$ is not constructively a field; I doubt factoring even univariate degree-$2$ polynomials is decidable over it.

Comment: @darijgrinberg You are right, I should speak of the field of real algebraic numbers. Fixed now.